# Multiple conditions on if

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, html-table, conditional-statements

I have an 8x8 table with `<td>` elements, each with its own unique id (the bottom-left one has 11, bottom right 18, top right 88 and top left 81).

Now I'm writing an IF statement but I don't know how to specify a condition.

Let's say we have `<td id="21">`. This one should fit the condition, as should `<td id="22">` etc.. As long as the `<td>` is in second row. It seems a bit redundant to write each of these conditions by hand?

var elemId1 holds the ID of the selected `<td>`;

```
case "♙":
{
    if(elemId1== (conditions))
    {
        //CODE TO MOVE THIS FIGURE      
    }
}
break;`
```

Comment: Clarify your question. What do you want to check? Are you asking "how to type an `if`" or "how do I check that something on the element is other something"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably better off using [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="81" data-row="8" data-column="1"></td>
        <td id="82" data-row="8" data-column="2"></td>
        <td id="83" data-row="8" data-column="3"></td>
        <td id="84" data-row="8" data-column="4"></td>
        ...
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <td id="71" data-row="7" data-column="1"></td>
         ...
    </tr>
    ...
</table>
```

then you can say:

```
if (document.getElementById(elemId1).dataset.column === "8") {
    // CODE TO MOVE THIS FIGURE
}
```

If you definitely want to stick with encoding the row and column in the id, you could use some integer math to decode it:

```
var row = Math.floor(elemId1 / 10);
var column = elemId1 % 10;
```

(`%` is the modulus operator; it gives the remainder of division)

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
if((elemId1==condition) || (elemId1==condition2) || (elemId1==condition3))//etc...
{
    //CODE TO MOVE THIS FIGURE      
}
```

|| is the logical OR operator means if elemId1 == condition OR elemId1 == condition2 etc... && is the logical AND operator...

Answer (score 0):

You can use parentheses and logical operators to use multiple conditionals.  You don't always need to use parentheses, but it can determine precedence in some cases.

Logical operators in JavaScript:

- && (and)
- || (or)
- ! (not)

The following reads "if a equals 4 and b equals 5":

```
if (a === 4 && b === 5)
if ((a === 4) && (b === 5))  // this works too (extra parentheses)
```

The following reads "if a equals 4 or 5":

```
if (a === 4 || a === 5)
```

The following reads"if a is not 5 and b is 1 or 2":

```
if (a !== 5 && (b === 1 || b === 2))
```

**EDIT:** After clarification, I think you are asking how to check if one variable equals one of many values?  You can do this with `Array.indexOf` which returns the position in an array that a given element is found (-1 if not found).  You can then convert the output of that method into a boolean (which you want to do since `0` means the element was found, but evaluates as falsy).

```
var haystack = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var needle = 4;
var needle_missing = 7;

if (!!~haystack.indexOf(needle)) // true
if (!!~haystack.indexOf(needle_missing)) // false
```

If you want to use `.indexOf` in IE8 then you'll meed a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Compatibility).

Comment: I see I have made myself rather unclear. I know about the logical operators in JavaScript, what I meant to ask was if there was a way to loop the conditions (what if there were a thousand <td> in second row?). What im trying to say is, is it possible to write if( for(i=1;i<9;i++){2+i /* string */})?

Answer (score 0):

```
if( elemId1.substr(0,1) == "2" ) { ... }
```

would be true for all cells with an id starting with 2 (all in the second row).